# How should the following code sample be amended inorder to be able to return the object?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services

The following code samples are from my aspx web service.

I would like to know how it should be changed so that i could return it as an object. All the following codes are on the web service and i am trying to call the object from Android.

So i would just like to know what changes i have to make in order to be able to pass the object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[WebMethod]
public object SomeMethod(Vehicle obj)
{
    return obj;
}

[WebMethod]
public void simpleCase()
{
    Vehicle obj = new Vehicle();
    obj.VehicleID = "KL-9876";
    obj.VehicleType = "Nissan";
    obj.VehicleOwner = "Sanjiva";
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string VehicleID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public string VehicleOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class Salesman
{

    [DataMember(Name = "a")]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "b")]
    public virtual int RoleId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "c")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "d")]
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "e")]
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; } 
} // "a","b","c","d"... are the values with which you'll identify the object properties - client side - when json parsing.




 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class SalesmanService 
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/get/{id}", 
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Salesman Get(string id)
        {
          //return your salesman
        }
    }
```

Don't forget about this in global.asax:

RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("salesman", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SalesmanService)));

Basically you should be able to make such a call:
"..localhost/salesman/50" for example

This is just a small sample, you'll have to put your hands on wcf and json for a wider understanding.

Comment: Hey what am i doing wrong in my code. I mean i am trying to pass the object so for it to happen what changes do i need to make in MY code. Apart from the jason and other things. JUST FROM MY CODE what changes do i need to make.

Comment: I don't know what kind of web service you're using or what your entire setup is therefore I cannot 100% edit your code to work out of the box, still - you can see the similarities between my "Salesman" class and your "Vehicle" class.

Comment: ok basically i want to pass an instance of the vehicle class to SomeMethod().. as in i want the ID Type and Owner to be passed to SomeMethod.. am i doing that part right? i dont think so. Thats what i want to know what small adjustments i need to make m8..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to create a web request from your Android app and receive that specific data after your request,this is a classic case of json and rest wcf web services.

Here you have a link for how to start the server side:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

And this is a link that shows you how to consume it client side:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

I hope this is more or less what you were looking for.

Comment: Hey actually, pretty much that's the scenario. But actually looking for the amendments that i need in this code. Android side is pretty alright. Just want to know how to amend this part of the code m8.